# How to set time zone for `DateListLogPlot`?

Tags: plotting, date-and-time, time-series

Sample data:

```
toyData = {
 {FromDateString["2021-12-05T22:32:00", TimeZone -> 0], 1},
 {FromDateString["2021-12-05T23:32:00", TimeZone -> 0], 2}}
```

Plot:

```
DateListLogPlot[toyData]
```

[image]
Although the data is given with `TimeZone->0`, the plot is in my local time zone (-5). How do I get a plot in UTC (or call it GMT if you must)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And right after I posted, I figured it out:

```
Block[{$TimeZone = 0}, DateListLogPlot[toyData]]
```

Kid of clumsy, but it works.